# Getting IntelliJ to show all errors of an Ant build

Tags: ant, ide, intellij-idea, stack-trace

How can I display all of the errors from an Ant build? I'd like to see those 21 other errors.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest trying to `Toggle tree/text mode` - on the left hand side of the Messages window

[image]

Comment: Doing that still says `... 21 more`. Since it still didn't show all of the issues, I assumed it wasn't strictly related to IntelliJ.

Answer (score 2):

The stack trace describes only one error, and the `... 21 more` string indicates 21 other methods that were the original call hierarchy.

IDEs will usually suppress the base caller information because it will not be specific to the error, such as the framework/tool internal calls.

To see the entire stack trace, either adjust your IDE settings, or run `ant` on the command line, where the entire stack trace will be printed.

Comment: Thanks for the wording correction. Do you know of such a setting in IntelliJ?

Comment: That I'm not sure about. I was not able to replicate the shortened stack trace during an `ant` build in IDEA 11.0.2, or find a setting that would control it. Why do you need to see the entire call stack of the error?

Comment: Alex: I'm working with proprietary and buggy ant scripts. I have a feeling seeing the full stack trace may help me debug my current issue.